# Jquery Adding Image Attribute Fix

Tags: jquery

How can I Add an image element through jquery, I am trying but it is not working. 
 When I upload a file, My image disappeared automatically. Am doing something wrong. Any Help will be Appreciated.

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
     $fileCount = this.files.length;
     $(this).prev().text( " <img src='https://i.imgur.com/WXGYX4O.png' width='53px'> " + $fileCount + ' Pic selected');
 })
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.form {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.img_Camera_icon {
    width: 53px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="form">

    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WXGYX4O.png" alt="" class="img_Camera_icon">
        0 Pic selected
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" type="file">
       
     
   </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `.text()`

use `.html()`, you might guess the difference